# Caesar cipher code is not cleared by check50, cannot figure out why

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I coded the assignment and followed the best that I could. I can pass all of the Check50 arguments except one! Help?? The validation is correct, but when I run the debugger, it begins to give me problems around the ciphering section. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int arg, string argv[])
{

//KEY VALIDATION
if (arg != 2) //checks to make sure that arg is 2 (for # of arguments)
{
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}

else if  (arg == 2)
{ // checks key for validity
    for(int i = 0, len = strlen(argv[1]); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //int key = atoi(argv[1]);
}
//ciphering


int key = atoi(argv[1]);
string plain = get_string("plaintext: ");
int len_plain = strlen(plain);
string cipher = plain;

 for (int x = 0; x < len_plain; x++)
        {
            if (plain[x] >= 'a' && plain[x] <= 'z')
            {
                cipher[x] = ((plain[x] + key)%122);
                if (cipher[x]<97)
                {
                    cipher[x] = cipher[x] + 96;
                }
            }
            else if (plain[x] >= 'A' && plain[x] <= 'Z')
            {
                cipher[x] = ((plain[x] + key)%90);
                if (cipher[x] < 65)
                {
                    cipher[x] = cipher[x] + 64;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cipher[x] = plain[x];
            }
        }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);
}
```

the check50 results I keep getting are,

```
:) caesar.c exists.
:) caesar.c compiles.
:) encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
:) encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
:) encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
:) encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
***:( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
output not valid ASCII text
```

Comment: When you ran `./caesar 65` by hand and typed in `barfoo`, what result did you get?

Comment: It shows nothing inside of the terminal but when I look through it with the debugger, the value assigned to `cipher` is 0x603270 "\211\210\231\215\226\226". Seems really weird to me.

Comment: `b` is ascii `98` and `(98+65)%122 == 41` finally `41 + 96 ==  137`. But `137` is not an alpha character as you intend. Just step thru the code line by line to see the same and also to understand what it does for the other characters. That is, your  first `if` block logic does not look correct.

Comment: I have come to that conclusion as well. The math just doesn't make sense to me at this point. How does the code work on other keys and words that are lowercase, but not in this one instance?

Comment: Because the `key` value influences whether the final cipher char ends up being in the valid alpha range or not.

Comment: correct but I technically do not have control over what the key is, which means it is in my math somewhere. The check50 runs the key as 65. The program is supposed to loop around the alphabet, and is somehow supposed to return an o.

Comment: I didn't say the key is the problem. I meant that your code handling of the key is the problem. So now you know your maths/logic is wrong. So you need to sit down with a piece of paper to work that out and then go back to code it.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("ciphertext: ");  
for (int x = 0, y = len_plain; x < y; x++)
    {
        //Use islower and isupper instead of typing so much words
        if islower(code[i])
        {
            printf("%c", (((code[i] + k) - 97) % 26) + 97);
        }
        else if isupper(code[i])
        {
            printf("%c", (((code[i] + k) - 65) % 26) + 65);
        }
        //If neither then just print it
        else
        {
            printf("%c", code[i]);
        }
    }
printf("\n")
```

Comment: This should work, but because of the specifics for the assignment, check50 will not clear it. The last line of code in the program must print out **ciphertext: followed by the changed text**

Comment: Exaimz,  Suggest your simply insert that couple of lines of code.   And how were we to know that detail, since it was not specified in the question?